# How can you search Github project Network for unmerged commits to a particular file?

Tags: python, git, github

I'm working on a project that is hosted @ Github.com
It seems that forum/models.py has some errors in it that are preventing me from syncdb.

I was curious if there was a way to search through the network to find all the changes that had been made in the entire Branch Network to forum/models.py to see if someone had fixed the errors already.

this is the Project:
http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG/network

These branches have not been merged into the main project yet.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is to do something like the following:

```
git log branch1 branch2 branch3 -- forum/models.py
```

where `branch1` etc. are the various branches, which you would need local copies of.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Github:
There isn't a search for unmerged commits, but if you hit the [forkqueue](http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG/forkqueue) you'll get a nice list of unmerged commits.
Assuming that people wrote good commit messages, you might be able to find the fix there if it exists.

For other projects the forkqueue URL would be:
http://github.com/project_name/project_name/forkqueue

Comment: Sadly, "this feature has been retired."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:
[Git history commands](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#exploring-git-history)

HIH

...richie

Answer (score 0):

May be 'git blame' can help you, if you know a line where error is located.

[git blame manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-blame.html)